# can you change the colour of the comments in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

can you have multi-coloured comments in vs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [Better Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aaron-bond.better-comments) extension to categorize your annotations in Visual Studio if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Can not use Visual Studio itself for multi-color comments.
You must install the plugin or extension